# HTML/CSS: Bold tag (<b>) with CSS style font-weight normal: What is the expected visual result?

Tags: html, css

I am writing a very simple HTML parser, using a strict subset of HTML 5.

As I understand, it is valid HTML 5 to write: `<b style="font-weight: normal">`  If not, please explain why.

What is the expected visual output: bold or normal?  In my emperical tests, I see normal (non-bold) text.

Is there a section of the HTML 5 standard that explains order of precedence with respect to HTML tags vs CSS styles?  I could not find anything.

I am OK to see practical answers that only use existing, major web browsers, instead of the the HTML 5 (living) standard.  I only have access to major web browsers on Linux.

FYI: My *Google-fu* failed me when I asked this question about HTML/CSS ambiguity.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the question - yes the b tag still exists, though it no longer is stated as making text bold as in previous versions but browsers I've looked at still seem to make the text bold. The ones I've inspected do that through their user interface style sheet in the usual way, viz font-weight: bold, but putting font-weight normal in the style as you have done overrides this.

Comment: *I could not find anything* --> there is no one because it's about only CSS and not HTML. The CSS specification detail this and in all the case an inline style will always win over any other style (unless it's `an !important` one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting directly from the [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-b-element):

> Style sheets can be used to format b elements, just like any other element can be restyled. Thus, it is not the case that content in b elements will necessarily be boldened.

In general, what you see by default is provided by the browser, and any CSS you define will override the browsers' defaults. This is true also for the `b` tag, which in fact doesn't mean "bold" but actually means "bring attention to", a goal which many different non-bold stylings can accomplish.

So to answer your question, in your example I'd expect the text to be non-bold.